# how to upload file on google Drive in java spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

what change need to made in my this code so its save my file on drive and get that saved url for view that file in google drive

```
private void saveFile(MultipartFile multipartFile, int id) throws Exception {
    String destination = "/images/" + id + "/"  + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
    File file = new File(destination);
    multipartFile.transferTo(file);
}
```

and how to restrict other user to access that file link

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads#multipart

Comment: any working example link